# Activate different property files depending on environment or testing or prod

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, configuration, h2

I am not able to figure how to load, in spring boot, a property files with oracle related credentials and, while executing unit and integration tests, a property files with H2 related credentials only (as I dont want to to create manually all the boiler plate configuration).
Hope someone has that knowledge or can give me some guidance,

Answer (score 0):

If your databases (dev, test, prod, ...) have **different names**, there's a query which tells you which database you're currently connected to:

```
SQL> select sys_context('userenv', 'db_name') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','DB_NAME')
---------------------------------------------------------
XE

SQL>
```

According to what it returns, *activate different property files* (whatever that is; I'm not familiar with the rest of tags you used).